# Use async iterator triggered by a custom function in main scope

Tags: javascript, async-await, iterator

What I want to do is to create an iterator, which is only triggered when an external function is called, say an external event.

An iterator that simply waits for custom events.

```js
function createIteratorWithFunction() {
  var thingThatResolves;
  var asyncIterable = {
    thingThatResolves,
    [Symbol.asyncIterator]() {
      return {
        next() {
          return (new Promise((resolve, reject) => asyncIterable.thingThatResolves = (resolve))).then(_ => ({
            value: _,
            done: false
          }));

        },
        return () {
          return {
            done: true
          }
        }
      };
    }
  };
  return asyncIterable;

}

iter = createIteratorWithFunction();
(async function() {
  for await (let val of iter) {
    console.log(val);
  }
})()
```

```html
<button onclick="iter.thingThatResolves('execute');iter.thingThatResolves(3)">execute next!</button>
```

As you can see, it only resolves 'execute', but not 3, of course because promises can't be resolved more than once, and it only is updated asynchronously, I understand this, but since the iterator is async, how would I create a queue, so that any values that could've synchronously been triggered are retrieved by `next()`, as well?

Comment: JS note: If you're writing JS that's so modern it uses async and iterators using symbol properties, please also use modern JS for that button, not a legacy `onclick` HTML attribute =)

Comment: this might be of interest https://slikts.github.io/queueable/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have this feeling that there's a more elegant solution involving promise chains, but it's escaping me at the moment. :-) See inline comments:

```js
function createIteratorWithFunction() {
    // Our pending promise, if any
    let promise = null;
    // The `resolve` function for our `pending` promise
    let resolve = null;
    // The values in the queue
    const values = [];
    // The async iterable
    const asyncIterable = {
        add(value) {
            // Add a value to the queue; if there's a pending promise, fulfill it
            values.push(value);
            const r = resolve;
            resolve = pending = null;
            r?.();
        },
        [Symbol.asyncIterator]() {
            return {
                async next() {
                    // If we don't have a value...
                    while (!values.length) {
                        // ...we need to wait for one; make sure we have something
                        // to wait for
                        if (!resolve) {
                            pending = new Promise(r => { resolve = r; });
                        }
                        await pending;
                    }
                    // Get the value we waited for and return it
                    const value = values.shift();
                    return {
                        value,
                        done: false,
                    };
                },
                return() {
                    return {
                        done: true,
                    };
                }
            };
        }
    };
    return asyncIterable;
}

const iter = createIteratorWithFunction();
(async function() {
    for await (let val of iter) {
        console.log(val);
    }
})();

document.getElementById("execute").addEventListener("click", () => {
    iter.add("execute");
    iter.add(3);
});
```

```html
<button id="execute">execute next!</button>
```

One of the key things here is that an async iterable can have overlapping iterations, and it has to not get confused by that. This implementation avoids that by creating the promise it'll wait on synchronously if it needs one.

```js
function createIteratorWithFunction() {
    // Our pending promise, if any
    let promise = null;
    // The `resolve` function for our `pending` promise
    let resolve = null;
    // The values in the queue
    const values = [];
    // The async iterable
    const asyncIterable = {
        add(value) {
            // Add a value to the queue; if there's a pending promise, fulfill it
            values.push(value);
            const r = resolve;
            resolve = pending = null;
            r?.();
        },
        [Symbol.asyncIterator]() {
            return {
                async next() {
                    // If we don't have a value...
                    while (!values.length) {
                        // ...we need to wait for one; make sure we have something
                        // to wait for
                        if (!resolve) {
                            pending = new Promise(r => { resolve = r; });
                        }
                        await pending;
                    }
                    // Get the value we waited for and return it
                    const value = values.shift();
                    return {
                        value,
                        done: false,
                    };
                },
                return() {
                    return {
                        done: true,
                    };
                }
            };
        }
    };
    return asyncIterable;
}

const iter = createIteratorWithFunction();
(async function() {
    for await (let val of iter) {
        console.log("first:", val);
    }
})();
(async function() {
    for await (let val of iter) {
        console.log("second:", val);
    }
})();

document.getElementById("execute").addEventListener("click", () => {
    iter.add("execute");
    iter.add(3);
});
```

```html
<button id="execute">execute next!</button>
```

I'm never happy when I have to make the promise's `resolve` function accessible outside the promise executor function (the function you pass `new Promise`), but as I say, the elegant solution with promise chains is escaping me. I sense strongly that it's there...somewhere... :-)

Comment: That code is really pretty, and yes, I have no idea how extract the resolve out of the promise, without simply setting it to a variable out of scope. But at least, it is scoped, so no big deal, right.

Comment: @Rainb - Exactly, we don't have it out there for just any code to muck with. :-D If whatever is hanging out in the very far reaches of the back of my mind ever comes into focus, I'll update the answer and ping you. I think there's a better way. Thanks for the interesting question!

Answer (score 1):

Another idea & way of doing this,  you could use custom events, one advantage is that the code is much easier to reason with.

Below I've knocked up a simple example, it also allows you to cancel the iterator & handle errors.  `makeIter` simple gives you 4 functions,

1. add = use this to add an item to the itterator.
2. iter = this is the iterator you can `for await` on.
3. done = if were done, you can call this and let the GC do it's thing.
4. error = allows you to put an error into the iterator, you can test this by un-commenting the last line.

To prevent any race conditions I've simply used a stack..

```js
function makeIter() {
  const obj = new EventTarget();
  const evName = 'my-iter'; 
  
  const stack = [];
  
  obj.addEventListener(evName, e => {
    stack.push(e.detail);
    resolve();
  }); 

  async function *iter() {
    while (true) {
      await new Promise(r => resolve = r);
      while (stack.length) {
        const s = stack.shift();
        if (s.resolve) yield(s.resolve);
        if (s.reject) throw s.reject;
        if (s.cancel) return;
      }
    }
  }
  function ev(p) {
    obj.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent(evName, {detail:p}));
  }
  
  return {
    error: (e) => ev({reject: e}), 
    done: () => ev({cancel: true}),
    add: item => ev({resolve: item}),
    iter: iter()
  }
}




///testing...
const test = makeIter();

(async function () {
  try {
    for await (const item of test.iter) {
      console.log(item);
    }
  } finally {
    console.log('iter done');
  }
}()); 

test.add('hello');
setTimeout(() => test.add('there'), 100);
setTimeout(() => {test.add('1'); test.add('2'); test.add('3'); }, 200);
setTimeout(() => test.add('4'), 400);

setTimeout(() => test.done(), 1000);
//setTimeout(() => test.error(new Error('oops')), 1000);
```

Comment: I'm slightly iffy on using an HTML element just for the event dispatch it provides. Observer/observable is not really that hard to implement. Still, I'd consider this a minor point. This does save up on lines of code in the example. Overall, pretty good solution.

Comment: @VLAZ  Yeah good point, I've taken out the Element and used EventTarget constructor directly..